# Access to Restricted data types and implement in development environment

Tags: google-fit

We are developing application that needs write access to restricted data types. And looks like Google has stopped taking new request for whitelisting apps.

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#restricted_data_types

> Note: Google has temporarily stopped taking new requests to write to restricted data types. We are updating our policy and process for reviewing requests and will update this documentation again when we resume.

Does anyone from Google have any idea when they will resume it?

Also: Is there a way to implement/write restricted data in development environment or debug build without whitelisting, and whitelist app before going to production?

Answer (score 2):

There is no timeline yet for when this will be available.

(Source: I work on Google Fit)

Comment: Thanks for update @andy. Is it completely stopped? I am seeing some changes on Page https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/restricted. It says lib will allows limited request for testing. But, API is not behaving that way. Do you know when it will be rolled out?

Comment: Can you please share if there is any update on timeline?